# Issue with Script tag inside Javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, adsense, geoip

[This page](http://101greatgoals.com/geoip-test.php) should display a Google ad.

I Tried everything but it's not working. I think that the problem is with the closing script tag - `</script>.`

Can you please copy the source code and test it?

I really couldn't make the ad appear till now even if it's working outside the javascript code.

Comment: Please copy the relevant source code into your post here or, even better, reproduce the problem in a jsFiddle.

Comment: `Can you please copy the source code and test it?` No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `</script>` embedded inside a JavaScript string literal which is interpreted as the end of `<script>` tag by the browser. There are simple workarounds, the simplest one is to split any `</script>` present inside a string literal using the `+` sign:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = "</scr" + "ipt>";
</script>
```

Looking at your page however, I doubt if the above changes will be enough. Instead of using `.innerText`:

1. use `document.createElement` to create a div (and script) element
2. use `element.appendChild` to append that div inside another element

Comment: I've improved it a bit - [link](http://101greatgoals.com/geoip-test.php) Still not what I want. The JS files are not showing their code like this.

Comment: You're close. You can use `$.getScript` to load JavaScript files dynamically (e.g. after you have determined that the country is not US). This function also provides callback support, so you can call your render ad function inside the callback.